# configure: error: APR-util version 1.2.0 or later is required

Tags: apache, configure, apr

I find the following error when I installed httpd-2.2.21:

```
  checking for APR-util version 1.2.0 or later... no
  configure: error: APR-util version 1.2.0 or later is required
```

I've installed apr-1.4.5, apr-util-1.3.12.
then i do configure:

> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/apache --with-apr=/usr/local/apr/bin/apr-1-config --with-apr-util=/usr/local/apr-util/bin/apu-1-config --enable-so --enable-dav --enable-maintainer-mode --enable-rewrite

I don't know why.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see this error in old apache httpd version, the new apache package has included apr source code under folder srclib, so if you see this error, just add with ./configure

```
--with-apr=$APACHE_SOURCE/srclib --with-apr-util=$APACHE_SOURCE/srclib  --with-included-apr
```

Answer (score 1):

When you download Apache (`httpd 2.4`), there is a directory which is called `/srclib`.

cd into that directory with `cd /srclib`. Open your browser and go to http://apr.apache.org/download.cgi and download the .apr files into the directory.

```
wget <link>
```

Unzip and extract it into srclib directory. After extracting, make sure you rename it just "apr"; example:

```
mv apr.1.5.1 apr
```

Now, it should read the `.apr` files from that folder. After that it will ask for `apr-utils` too; make sure you follow the same procedure.

PS: The apr files in `/usr/local` are files which are already built. so they won't work.

Answer (score 1):

you need to install **apr-util-1.5.4**

Download it from [archive.apache.org](https://archive.apache.org/dist/apr/apr-util-1.5.4.tar.gz)

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/src/httpd-2.4.17/srclib/apr-util/ --with-apr=/usr/local/src/httpd-2.4.17/srclib/apr/
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation it appears the you should be giving the top level directory as the argument for the with-apr and with-apr-util options.

Try this:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/apache --with-apr=/usr/local/apr/ --with-apr-util=/usr/local/apr-util/ --enable-so --enable-dav --enable-maintainer-mode --enable-rewrite
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have bundled apr and apu installed (make sure you libapr1-dev and libaprutil1-dev installed), don't pass any argument for apr.

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/apache --enable-so --enable-dav --enable-maintainer-mode --enable-rewrite
```

If you want to use the apr and apu included in srcdir, `--with-included-apr` will be enough to add as argument. Externally compiled apr/apu currently buggy. Update your source code and re-compile if you want to have up to date version.

Answer (score 0):

I found I experienced this problem under Solaris 11 with httpd-2.2.22. My config.log showed that the program testing the apr-util version produced a compile error because apu_version.h includes apr_version.h, but the test program did not include a -I directive for the apr include directory. I worked around this problem by providing the apr include directive explicitly in CPPFLAGS. Adapted to your example it would look like this:

```
CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/apr/include" ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/apache --with-apr=/usr/local/apr --with-apr-util=/usr/local/apr-util --enable-so --enable-dav --enable-maintainer-mode --enable-rewrite
```

Note that I have also modified your --with-apr and --with-apr-util clauses. I think these should both point to the top-level directory and not to the config program. YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found a solution to resolve this issue. 
Please configure apr-util using as below
Download apr and apr-util from apache.org and untar it and compile apr first.
Go to extracted apr path and compile apr.
Ex:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/apache/apache.2.4.55/apr
make
make test
make install
```

Next complile apr util using apr

```
./configure --with-apr=/usr/apache/apache.2.4.55/apr/bin/apr-1-config
```

and use the same apr path at final installation aswell Ex:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/apache/apache.2.4.55 --with-apr-util=/usr/apache/apache.2.4.55/apr-util/ --with-apr=/usr/apache/apache.2.4.55/apr/bin/apr-1-config  --enable-so --enable-mods-shared=all --enable-proxy --enable-rewrite --disable-deflate --with-ldap-include=/usr/apache/apache.2.4.55/ldap/include --with-ldap-lib=/usr/apache/apache.2.4.55/ldap/lib --with-ldap --enable-ldap --with-ldap-sasl --with-pcre=/usr/apache/apache.2.4.55/pcre/bin/pcre-config --with-ssl=/usr/apache/apache.2.4.55/ssl --enable-ssl --enable-so
```